# How to calculate document size in Cloudant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I'll use Cloudant to store some documents returned from an API, how can I estimate the **approximate** space needed by document, here is a sample document:

```
{
  "document_tone": {
    "tone_categories": [
      {
        "tones": [
          {
            "score": 0.25482,
            "tone_id": "anger",
            "tone_name": "Anger"
          },
          {
            "score": 0.345816,
            "tone_id": "disgust",
            "tone_name": "Disgust"
          },
          {
            "score": 0.121116,
            "tone_id": "fear",
            "tone_name": "Fear"
          },
          {
            "score": 0.078903,
            "tone_id": "joy",
            "tone_name": "Joy"
          },
          {
            "score": 0.199345,
            "tone_id": "sadness",
            "tone_name": "Sadness"
          }
        ],
        "category_id": "emotion_tone",
        "category_name": "Emotion Tone"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you save your json in a file, you could try something like

```
cat file.json | jq --compact-output '' | wc -c
```

which says that the file above is about 398 chars. In Cloudant you also may incur index space, depending on your setup.

Comment: Nice answer, +1

Comment: the file.json would also need an `_id` and `_rev` value. e.g.

    "_id":"6ba8ad584a941f773b1e73f3e30e9622","_rev":"1-8ebe0ed680c8165c10641a1b237918a2"

which adds to the storage requirements.

Comment: Thanks! Can I consider 2 byte per char? As described in this reference:
http://ubjson.org/type-reference/value-types/

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, you can make a GET request against https://$USERNAME.cloudant.com/$DATABASE it will return details about the database for your accurate estimation. More information can be found here: https://docs.cloudant.com/database.html#read